# Why can't i access a child node?

Tags: javascript

Currently learning javascript and I get an error saying 'childNodes [1] is undefined', but (id="intro") has two children, so why can't i access the second child (Hello world!)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="intro">
<h1>DOM Lesson one</h1>
<p>Hello world!</p>
</p>

<script>
try
{
var txt=document.getElementById("intro").childNodes[1].nodeValue;
document.write(txt);
}
catch(err)
{
alert(err);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Docs for reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1).  Particularly note the part "The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but (id="intro") has two children

It doesn't.

- You cannot have an `h1` element inside a `p` element
- The end tag for the `p` element is optional

Your markup is equivalent to:

```
<p id="intro">
</p><h1>DOM Lesson one</h1>
<p>Hello world!</p>
</p>
```

The paragraph has one child node, a text node with spaces/new lines in it.

---

Even if that wasn't the case (let's [try it](http://jsbin.com/dokekuxa/1/edit?html,output) with a div instead of a paragraph), the white space will still create text nodes, so the node at index 1 will be the `h1` element.

---

You then have another problem, [the `nodeValue` of an element is `null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue).

You need to get the `firstChild` of the element to get the text node inside it, and then get the `nodeValue` of that.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, much appreciated. I'm confused by "white space will still create text nodes", which makes me think of these as mini-objects nested inside a parent node object; I'll play around with your last comment about firstChild.

Answer (score 0):

A `<p>` element cannot contain an `<h1>` element, therefore `childNodes[1]` does not actually exist.